# Jolt transform to stringify object into a parent

Tags: json, jolt

I have an array of JSON objects that I need to stringify and add the stringify result to a parent using jolt.

**Input**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "john",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "tom",
    "age": 12
  }
]
```

**Desired output**

```json
[
  {
    "Details": " \"name\": \"john\",\"age\": 12"
  },
  {
    "Details": " \"name\": \"tom\", \"age\": 12 "
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following specification

```json
[
  { // double-quotes( " ) of VALUES are replaced with "\" 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": ["=toInteger", "=concat('\"',@(1,&),'\"')"]
      }
    }
  },
  { // double-quotes( " ) of KEYS are replaced with "\" 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$|@": "&3.\"&2\":&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate newly formed keys to be respective components of the new arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[&2].Details"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate newly formed arrays to generate strings
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join(',',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]